Expectation of a bivariate function vs the expectation of the transformed variables
Let $(X_1,X_2)\sim f(x_1,x_2)$, also $\phi=g(x_1,x_2)$, where $g$ is invertible with respect to both $x_1$ and $x_2$, we can obtain the density of $\phi\sim p(\phi)$ through the Jacobian rule.
My question is: is the expectation with respect to $f(x_1,x_2)$
$$E(g(x_1,x_2))=\int\int g(x_1,x_2)f(x_1,x_2)dx_1dx_2$$
equivalent to the expectation
$$E(\phi)=\int \phi p(\phi)d\phi\;?$$
if not, how to show they are equivalent?

Notational issues aside. equality is assured by the law of the unconscious statistician.  For any random variable $\phi$ with a density function, the expectation is defined as the second integral. The law of the unconscious statistician, which you have used in your first integral, says that since $\phi$ is a function of another variable, its expectation can be computed via the formula in your first integral, and the value of that first integral is guaranteed to be the same as $E[\phi)]$.
